# How to Linking two checkbox Array together JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to connect two checkbox together , so that When clicked main checkbox then checked its child.
with below code I retrieve data from database:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_show_all_receivers))
      {
          $option .= ' <pre> <input onclick="func()" type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="check_Main[]" value = "'.$row['user_username'].'">'. row['user_username'].'    
                             <input  type="checkbox" class="checkbox-inline" name="check_child[]"  id="check_child[]" value = "'.$row['user_mobile'].'">  '.$row['user_mobile'].' 
                       </pre>';

      }
```

and show the items:

```
<?php echo $option; ?>
```

How possible if Main box checked then will checked its child too.

Its my JavaScript code but I think have to use via loop:
It just work first child not others.

```
        <script>
           function func()
               {
                   document.getElementById('check_child[]').checked = true ;
               }
         </script>
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parent and child checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155136/parent-and-child-checkboxes)

Comment: @evolutionxbox unfortunately no please help with my method

Comment: `check_child[]` this isn't a valid id. Consider using `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes script in that link helped me and I updated it with loop. thanks

Comment: why it dose not work with "/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" version?

Comment: What doesn’t work? I’m not sitting at your screen, I don’t know what you’re talking about.

Comment: in that link we have script of JQuery version "1.5.1" , OK? but when I using  version "3.4.1" it dose not work. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

IDs should be unique. In your case, you could use the query's row number in order to build an unique ID with a common prefix, it's generally good practice.

Here's a CodePen that works
https://codepen.io/Raven0us/pen/abvJqLP

```html
<label for="checkbox-parent">Parent</label>
<input type="checkbox" onchange="func(event)" name="checkbox_parent" id="checkbox-parent">

<div>
    <label for="checkbox-child-1">Child 1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_child_1" id="checkbox-child-1" class="checkbox-child">
    <label for="checkbox-child-2">Child 2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_child_2" id="checkbox-child-2" class="checkbox-child">
    <label for="checkbox-child-3">Child 3</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_child_3" id="checkbox-child-3" class="checkbox-child">
</div>
```

I changed `onclick` to `onchange`, some people prefer `click`, mostly for legacy reasons (I think?), but I wouldn't. Moreover, I passed the actual event to the function, so it's available if we want to check stuff about it.

```js
function func(event) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-child').forEach(checkboxChild => {
        checkboxChild.checked = event.target.checked;
    })
}
```

The handler gets all the related checkboxes, based on a common class which can repeat, unlike IDs, and loop through the returned `NodeList` and update their value based on parent checkbox value. So, checking or unchecking parent will update children as well.

Comment: Hi @Ravenous , but children’s id are in loop idk how many are there to set unique id. It retrieves from database

Comment: Before `while`, you can simply have a variable `$index = 0;`, and for each row, you just increment that `$index++`, and use `$index` when setting up your markup so you'll get unique IDs. To get it working like it does in the example, you don't need the IDs, though.

Answer (score 0):

[Parent and child checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155136/parent-and-child-checkboxes)

with above script by @CoolEsh I could solve this problem and update with loop to specific every parents and their children :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
  <script>
        var checkboxHandlerObj = {
  init: function() {
    $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.parentClicked);
    $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class^="parent-"]').click(checkboxHandlerObj.childClicked);
  },

  parentClicked: function() {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
      $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="parent-' + $(this).attr('id') + '"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }
  },

  childClicked: function() {
    var temp = $(this).attr('class').split('-');
    var parentId = temp[1];

    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
      $('#' + parentId).attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
      var atLeastOneEnabled = false;
      $('#customerServices input:checkbox[class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
          atLeastOneEnabled = true;
        }
      });
      if (!atLeastOneEnabled) {
        $('#' + parentId).removeAttr('checked');
      }
    }
  }

};

checkboxHandlerObj.init();

         </script>
```

and PHP loop:

```
<div id="customerServices">
<?php
$x = 1;
$id = 1;
while($x <= 5) {
    $x++;
$option .= '<input id="'.$id.'"  class="parent" type="checkbox" name="check_Main[]" value = "1">1
<input  type="checkbox" name="check_child[]" class="parent-'.$id.'"  value = "2">  2 <br> ';

$id++ ;
} 

 echo $option;
?>
</div>
```

It worked with unique Id. Thanks For @Ravenous and @evolutionxbox